# How to use PANDAS to find the max number for a year in a CSV file?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am working with a csv file called namedata.csv. It is formatted 'year','name','gender'(M or F), 'number'. the number is the amount of times that name was given to a child in that year. My task is to find the name with the highest usage number for whatever year is input. I am trying to use PANDAS since it seems to make it a much simpler task.

```
df = pd.read_csv('namedata.csv', header=None)
df.columns = ['year','name','gender','number']
df.sort_values(['number', 'year'], ascending=[False, True])
```

So far this is what I have, I have also been able to sort the data both by ascending years and by the highest numbers. What I want to do is to sort by both year ascending and the highest number that way I can find the highest male or female number.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ['year','name','gender','number']
# Example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [2020, 'Salome', 'F', 2],
    [2019, 'Maylis', 'F', 3],
    [2020, 'Heloise', 'F', 4],
    [2019, 'Heloise', 'F', 5],
], columns=columns)
# Slice the dataframe to restrict it to the desired subset
df_sliced = df.loc[(df['year'] == 2019) & (df['gender'] == 'F')]
# Use idxmax() or argmax() (argmax is deprecated on latest pandas versions) method on the number column to get the row index of the highest number value
# Use this row index as index, and the column 'name' as column output
name = df_sliced.loc[df_sliced['number'].idxmax(), 'name']
print(name)
```

> 'Heloise'

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for thank you. Correct me if I am wrong but would 'Heloise' not be the name given to the most girls in 2019? if so how would I be able to fix the code to make sure it gave the proper name?

Comment: Hello Aaron, please excuse me for the very bad mistake. The code is fixed. I did not run the test before, that is why :). I hope it helps